# proc sql mode function

Tags: sas

I know that in mysql there's no aggregate function to calculate the mode (you have to do many steps). But I think in a proc sql should be possible. Is there a way to do so?
The code would be sth like this:

```
select phones, mode(state_id)as state from
xxx.listings_abr3 
group by phones
```

the error is:

Function MODE could not be located.

thanks!

Comment: You're using SAS now, so why not use `proc means` or `proc summary`?

Comment: Also, no there is not a MODE() summary function built in to `proc sql`.

Comment: because I also do other things in the same proc sql, and don't want to do a many steps (I mean joining the result of proc means)... but if there's no other way....

Comment: FYI, http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/calculating-mean-median-and-mode-with-sq/ is a good description of how to calculate mode, and median, in SQL Server; SAS would allow this but won't allow the ordering in a subquery, so would require two (three really)  steps for median.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MODE` is possible in `proc sql`, with a subquery.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(7);
  do id = 1 to 100;
    x = rand('Geometric',.2);
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
 select x as mode from (
        select x, count(1) as count from have group by x
        ) 
    having count=max(count);
quit;
```

This takes advantage of the automatic remerging SAS will do for you; if you want to avoid that, you need to do a bit more work to get that having statement to work.

You still may need to do further work on this, as you might have multiple modes and this doesn't distinguish between them (it returns all modes).

Comment: This answer aside, I strongly support the idea of not using SQL to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Using the method Joe gives in his answer, here is how you would calculate modes by group:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(7);
  do n_group = 1 to 3;
      do id = 1 to 100;
        x = rand('Geometric',.2);
        output;
      end;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
 select n_group, x as mode from (
        select n_group, x, count(1) as count from have group by n_group, x
        )
    group by n_group
    having count=max(count);
quit;
```